# Sequence of least prime-multiples with smallest Hamming weight

Tags: prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

It is known that 
[Almost all primes have a multiple of small Hamming weight](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05974), which makes me wonder what is known about the least multiples of primes that have least Hamming weight.

**Questions:**

- what are the values of the sequence $$\mu(n)\quad :=\quad \min\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left( \min\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}:\ \ \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty d_i2^i}{p_n}=m\in\mathbb{N},\ \ \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty d_i=k,\ \ d_i\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace\right)$$,
  where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number?
  $\mu(1)=1,\ \mu(2)=1,\ \mu(3)=1,\ \mu(4)=1,\ \mu(5)=3,\ \mu(6)=5,\ \dots$
- for which $n$ is $H(p_n\mu(n)) \gt 6$ if $H()$ is denotes the Hammig weight of the argument ?

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question. If you want to calculate $\mu(6)$, say, you first find $p_6=13$, the sixth prime, then you find $13\times5=65=(1000001)_2$ has Hamming weight $2$, and obviously no multiple of $13$ is a power of $2$, so $\mu(6)=5$ (or is it $\mu(6)=2$?). Are the values of $\mu(n)$ tabulated at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\mu(6)=5$. I chose that on purpose because knowing the smallest factor $m$ that yields the smallest Hamming weight allows for easy calculation of that weight, but knowing the minimal Haming weight gives no way of easily calculating the minimal $m$ that yields that minimal weight, especially if the minimal Haming weight were proven by contradiction, i.e. the assumption that a higher Hamming weight were minimal led to cotradiction.

Comment: OK, then $\mu(8)=27$, since the eighth prime is $19$, and $19\times27=513=2^9+1$ has Hamming weight $2$, and $19m$ has Hamming weight greater than $2$ for all $m<27$. It seems to me there will be a lot of $n$ for which $\mu(n)$ will be considerably greater than $6$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson shame on me! I wanted to know the $p_n$ with a Hamming weight larger than 6; I edited the question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: $11\times3=33=2^5+1$, so $\mu(5)=3$, so I still don't follow you. $3^2\cdot331$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson today is not my day...

Comment: $7m=2^k+1$ is impossible, since $2^k+1\equiv0\bmod7$ has no solution, so $\mu(4)=1$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Hamming weight is the number of $1$ in the binary expansion, right?

Comment: @Sylvain yes, that's the definition of Hamming weights at least in the context of this question.

Comment: Do you know any value of $n$ for which $H>6$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson checking the linked paper for examples I saw that **Theorem 5** states that if the number $\Omega(2^n-1) \lt \frac{\log n}{\log k}$ then one of the prime factors of $2^n-1$ has the property that all of its multiples have Hamming weight of at least $k$; $\Omega()$ denotes the number of primefactors counted with multiples. Unfortunately no clue is given as to which of the factors has that property. The linked paper is real gem by the way.

Comment: Certainly the inequality holds if $2^n-1$ is prime, even with $k=n-1$, and there's only one prime factor, so that gives about $40$ examples.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the interest in my paper.

1. Here is a criterion for good candidates:
   if the order of 2 modulo $p$ is less than $p^{1/6}$, then
   six-fold sums $2^{i_1}+ \cdots + 2^{i_6}$ cannot cover all $p$ residue classes. (Often the 0-class mod $p$ is covered only with high iterations, but it is possible, it is covered earlier.
   Actually, a slightly weaker condition might suffice, as there are only Binomial(ord_p (2),6) expressions with distinct exponents.)
   As the order of $2$ is at least $\log_2(p+1)$,
   which is the case of Mersenne primes, $p$ needs
   to be at least $3 \times 10^9$.

Non-Mersenne primes with this criterion might be quite a bit larger.

2. At the time I wrote that paper, I did some experimental tests,
   which shows that smaller primes work,
   as the sumsets do not always grow with maximal speed.

Let us look at primes (not being Mersenne primes)
with quite small order of 2. Let
$A=(\{2^i: 0\leq i \leq \rm{ord}_p(2)-1\} ) \subset \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

For $p=178481$;
$|A|=23, |2A|=276, |3A|=2047, |4A|=10879, |5A|=42711, |6A|=113275,
|7A|=171810, |8A|=178480$,

which means one class is missing.
It is exactly the 0-class, which is needed so that the sumset is a multiple of $p$.

Only the 9-fold sumset contains the 0-class.